# List<String> to List<Integer> using Integer foo(String s)

Tags: java, list, java-8, java-stream

I've got a list `List<String>` (`list1`) and a function `Integer foo(String s)`. Using the power of Java 8 I want to convert `list1` to a `List<Integer>` by applying `foo` to each item of `list1`. The following code works but has a little problem:

```
List<Integer> list2 = list1.stream().mapToInt(s -> foo(s)).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

When `foo`returns `null` for some element of `list1` a `NullPointerException`is thrown. Additionally my solution looks a little bit inconvenient. So is there a better one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are mapping it to an `Integer`, I don't see the need to use `mapToInt` and then use `boxed`.

Instead, you could simple use `map` and then `filter` to exclude the nulls.

```
List<Integer> list2 =
    list1.stream()
       .map(s -> foo(s))
       .filter(Objects::nonNull)
       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you want to keep the nulls in the list, simply remove the `filter`

```
List<Integer> list2 =
    list1.stream()
       .map(s -> foo(s))
       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Instead of writing `s -> foo(s)`, one can also write `ClassName::foo` where `ClassName` is the class where `foo()` is declared

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the answer already given, you can do this:

```
List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
list1.forEach(s -> list2.add(foo(s)));
```